# Unable to launch Selenium chrome driver in Servlet (Java Dynamic Web Project)

Tags: java, selenium, servlets

I am trying to launch chrome driver from servlet but chrome driver doesn't launch, neither any error comes.

```
public class Hello extends GenericServlet {

    public final String url3 = "https://google.com";
    public WebDriver driver;

    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException {

        res.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.print("<html><body>");
        out.print("<b>hello generic servlet</b>");
        out.print("</body></html>");


        String exePath = "D:/MyPractice/SeleniumAutomation/chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to(url3);
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

When I go to this servlet URL just html content is printed but chrome driver is not launched.

Any solution for this?

Comment: did you try driver.get(url3);

Comment: yup tried. Didn't work